is it possible retrieve a Wix page collection, from outside by API?
My client has a Wix website showing some elements, using dynamic pages and collections.
He want to show these elements also on another web page, not on wix.
I'd like to use API to retrieve page collection from Wix, instead of web scraping.. but I don't know very well Wix backend. Is that possible? Where should I start to check?
thank you

There are probably a couple of ways to do this, but I think the easiest would be to use HTTP functions. Basically, you expose an API endpoint from your site that you can call externally. In the code for that endpoint you can retrieve the collection data and return it to the caller.
Be sure to understand the security implications of such an approach. If you don't add any checks, anybody will be able to call this endpoint to retrieve the data.
